# How to get list of records of a particular columnFamily?

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra and I want to fetch all the records from a column family, but I'm not getting how to do it. I don't have any key to fetch records. How to do it from command prompt? Is there any query?

Answer (score 1):

```
[default@unknown] help list;
list <cf>;
list <cf>[<startKey>:];
list <cf>[<startKey>:<endKey>];
list ... limit N;
List a range of rows in the column or supercolumn family.

example:
list Users[j:] limit 40;
```